# Where is the p4 binary installed to on OSX by default?

Tags: perforce

I have p4v installed on my mac but can't find the p4 binary. its not in the path so I can't do which p4. Does any one know the default location?

Comment: `find / -name p4` or perhaps `whereis p4`, if that's whereis is installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my Mac (OSX 10.7) it's at /usr/bin/p4, which ought to be on your path.

You should be able to find it using Spotlight if it's in a different place, or using the command:

```
sudo find / -type f | grep p4
```

Comment: I was mistakenly assuming that installing p4v would install p4 to the system too. thanks